# What do the numbers on my hub mean?

Tags: hub, giant

I have a Giant mountain bike front hub from a Giant P-XC2 wheelset with the inscription "12,23-12" on it. What do these numbers mean?

Comment: Do you have a make/model for the hub?

Comment: @Batman It's a Giant hub that was part of their P-XC2 wheelset.

Comment: Could well be the manufacturing date.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The bike is a 2013 model year, so that could make sense.